# Combine or merge word table with condition

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-table

The word document containing multiple tables. If any table having rows equal to value x (eg. 12) then delete first row and cut that table and paste it below the last row of previous table (means join the selected table with previous table at the end). The below code delete the first row but pasting the same table above the selected table. I have used copy in below code instead of cut.

```
Private Sub MergeTables()
Dim tbl As Table, r As Row
Dim i As Integer

With ActiveDocument
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    If tbl.Rows.Count = 12 Then
    With tbl
    .Rows(1).Delete
    tbl.Range.Copy 'Need to paste below last row of previous table

    'tbl.Range.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=wdGoToPrevious 'Pasting above the same table
    tbl.Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
    End With
    End If

Next tbl
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the first table's row count <> 12:

```
Sub MergeTables()
Dim TblSrc As Table, TblTgt As Table, Rng As Range
For Each TblSrc In ActiveDocument.Tables
    With TblSrc
      If .Rows.Count = 12 Then
        .Rows(1).Delete
        Set Rng = TblTgt.Range
        Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Rng.FormattedText = .Range.FormattedText
        .Delete
      Else
        Set TblTgt = TblSrc
      End If
    End With
Next
End Sub
```